# Beamer pause and numbering

Tags: beamer, counters, pause

I'm trying beamer for the first time (but have some experience with LaTeX). 
I want to use \pause and number some problems, but the numbers increment when I don't want them to. 
There must be a simple way to fix this, but I haven't found it yet.
Here is an example of code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newcounter{bar}
\newcommand{\pbctr}{%
   \stepcounter{bar}%
    \thebar}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some examples and problems}
\begin{block}{Problem \pbctr}
\begin{enumerate}
\item How many divisors does the number 2 have?
\pause
\item How many divisors does the number 4 have?
\pause
\item What is the smallest number with six divisors?
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\pause
\begin{block}{Problem \pbctr}
\begin{itemize}
\item Can I distribute evenly 30 apples amongst 5 children
\pause
\item Can I distribute evenly 33 apples amongst 6 children?
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
code
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem (i.e., the desired output)?

Answer (score 1):

In short: do nothing and let beamer deal with your problems :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Some examples and problems}
        \begin{problem}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item How many divisors does the number 2 have?
                \pause
                \item How many divisors does the number 4 have?
                \pause
                \item What is the smallest number with six divisors?
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{problem}
        \pause
        \begin{problem}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Can I distribute evenly 30 apples amongst 5 children
                \pause
                \item Can I distribute evenly 33 apples amongst 6 children?
            \end{itemize}
        \end{problem}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]